# How do I integrate PrivateIdentity authentication at HTML level?

Tags: html, authentication, iframe, identity, privateid

I want to integrate Private Identity authentication into my web app, at the HTML level. How do I do that? Where do I find the `iframe code` and how do I get an API key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to integrate private identity into your web app, you can get the iframe code from https://github.com/openinfer/PrivateIdentity/wiki/DIV-HTML and for API key you need to go to AWS Marketplace and subscribe to Private Identity then you will get the API key Another way you can contact to support@private.id